# Laravel .htaccess rewrite rule conversion to IIS

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, laravel

Laravel4 framework comes with a default .htaccess rule for create pretty urls.

The rule is this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Question:** Which is the equivalent in IIS ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [import Apache rules feature](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules) to convert Apache rule to IIS.

In your case, it will go as:

[image: import]

Or in the `web.config` file:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
```

Comment: @jcadiz how to add this code and where in public or in htacess. Please help

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, thanks to Oli Folkerd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Laravel4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of extra sections that are worth putting in your web.config file

The code below allows you to create restfull controllers using the additional PUT and DELETE HTTP verbs, and allows for laravel's custom error pages to be displayed when you are remotley debugging the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Laravel4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
            <add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```