# IIS URL Rewrite equivalent for Question2Answer mod_rewrite

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, question2answer

What IIS URL Rewrite rule set in web.config is equivalent to this mod_rewrite rule set provided in [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/)'s default .htaccess?

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

The rule differs from a typical WordPress-style rewrite in that nested path elements need to be passed through. Following is an example of a test URL that Question2Answer uses to verify rewriting is working, when Question2Answer is deployed into a `qa` directory on the server (deployment to the web root fails similarly):

```
http://localhost:32568/qa/url/test/%24%26-_~%23%25%5C%40%5E%2A%28%29%3D%21%28%29%5D%5B%60%27%3B%3A%7C%22.%7B%7D%2C%3C%3E%3F%23+%CF%80%C2%A7%C2%BD%D0%96%D7%A9?dummy=&param=%24%26-_%7E%23%25%5C%40%5E%2A%28%29%3D%21%28%29%5D%5B%60%27%3B%3A%7C%22.%7B%7D%2C%3C%3E%3F%23+%CF%80%C2%A7%C2%BD%D0%96%D7%A9
```

This is what IIS Manager's "Import mod_rewrite rules" feature came up with:

```xml
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.*)//(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="index.php?qa-rewrite={R:0}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I also added this so that the test URLs would fail in the same way as the actual navigation URLs:

```xml
<security>
   <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
```

There is no answer to a [question covering this](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/16782/setup-on-iis-7-5) on question2answer QA's site. Hopefully someone experienced in IIS URL Rewrite here will know.

Comment: Do you have access to the inetmgr MMC? If yes, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018538/laravel-htaccess-rewrite-rule-convertion-to-iis/15027668#15027668

Comment: @cheesemacfly: I do. Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, it didn't work. The rewriting works fine on a Linux deployment, but the Windows version fails on the multi-part paths. Perhaps IIS rewriting isn't exactly equivalent to Apache. How do you debug rewriting?

Comment: First think you can do is replace `Rewrite` with `Redirect` to see where it takes you. If not enough, you can use the [failed request tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules). If it doesn't help, edit your question adding your current rules!

Comment: @cheesemacfly: The redirect URL looked like fine, and I couldn't get the Fail Request Tracing Rules module to show up, so I posted the web.config rules as you suggested.

Comment: So when you use Redirect the page shows up as it should? (you don't get a 404 or any other issue?)

Comment: @cheesemacfly: The test URL was redirecting as I expected it to, but the page URLs with multiple path parts were not behaving in a way that made any sense. I tried again after your post, and now all the pages work, even though the tests still don't. It may have been a combination of forgetting to put Redirect back to Rewrite and of having a rewrite for Wordpress in the parent directory. Your inetmgr MMC suggestion was the key. Thanks! My guess is that I should vote this question for deletion as a duplicate. Thoughts?

Comment: You could probably post the working version of the `rules` section in your web.config as an answer, it could help someone else looking for those rules when using question2answer with IIS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration works:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="DeduplicateSlashes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.*)//(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="CleanRouting" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?qa-rewrite={R:0}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- Double escaping is needed for URLs with '+', e.g. for the account page for a username with a space. -->
    <security>
       <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have Q2A inside a subfolder called /qa/ and the above configuration is not working. Can you suggest what I must do to make it work?