# Error 500 when called index.php in laravel application (Windows environment)

Tags: php, docker, iis, laravel-5

I am deploying a laravel application inside windows based docker container using IIS.
When I run the application after running docker container the server.php page present at C:\inetpub\wwwroot works fine. However, C:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\index.php returns 500 error. I have enabled the logs, run composer update and applied directory permissions as well. But still no luck.

IIS10
PHP 7.0
Laravel 5.5

The log message is

> GET /public/index.php - 80 - 172.18.224.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+Touch;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 500 19 13 1

web.config file:

```
<configuration>
```

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />

    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
```

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Can you paste your log here?

Comment: The laravel.log file is empty due to some reason.

Comment: You have to enable logging and set right permissions on log file. Is your php  display_error on?

Comment: Display_error is on. When I check permissions of log file using PS it shows 
Access NT Authority\Interactive Allow FullControl

Comment: I think you have to check docker log that is in `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log`

Comment: This is the log generated
GET /public/index.php - 80 - 172.18.224.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+Touch;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 500 19 13 1

Comment: Can you please check permission on 'index.php' file, it should be 644

Comment: {"log":"ERROR ( message:Cannot find requested collection element. )\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-02-14T15:25:28.4315622Z"}
{"log":"Applied configuration changes to section \"system.applicationHost/applicationPools\" for \"MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST\" at configuration commit path \"MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST\"\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-02-14T15:25:29.565562Z"}
{"log":"ERROR ( message:Cannot find requested collection element. )\r\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2018-02-14T15:25:30.027562Z"}
 Logs obtained from json.log file

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head, these are the errors that I faced when setting up laravel:

1- Directory storage permissions

2- Directory bootstrap permissions

3- composer update

4- .env file is available

5- .env key is generated

6- database is there

7- database is configured correctly in .env

8- `php artisan serve` if the virtual server not configured

and if i got any of those i restart the server to update the values.

if the application was a repo and gave an error, sometimes the below artisan commands save the day:

`php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear`

Answer (score 0):

500.19 errors usually occur when you have configuration files that are not well formed. Enable Detailed errors in IIS and reproduce the issue. You will get a clear idea as to what is going wrong.

To enable Detailed errors in IIS - Click on the website ---> HTTP Errors--->Edit Feature Settings---->Detailed Errors.

Or you can follow this as well - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers/

Comment: I am deploying the image inside a docker container (Windows based). So this won't work unless there is some PS script available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import rule on IIS [View Apache Import Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules)

Take a look on stackoverflow thread [Laravel .htaccess rewrite rule convertion to IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018538/laravel-htaccess-rewrite-rule-convertion-to-iis)

If nothing will helpful check the "storage" folder permission in your project. Usually 500 comes with write permission or mis-configuration of server, may be due write permission error, the laravel.log may be empty!

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error is a Server Error. Seeing that your server.php page works fine, I would not think anything in your configuration files is causing the error. More likely that not, there is some php code in your index.php page that is causing the error. I suggest using xdebug to step through your code to locate the error.